# Is there any way to use other website font in email template?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I am creating an email template. Now i want to use the same font as my website font.

Is there any way to use my site font in email template?

Below is my html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>     
@font-face {
    font-family: 'XSANS';
    src: url('http://new.bama.ir/content/font/XTX-FNT-XEROSANS-REGULAR.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

.ab{ font-family: "XSANS";
 direction: rtl;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 22px;
    text-align: justify;
color:#919191}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="ab">این برای تست . این برای تست . این برای تست .
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now problem is my font of template is different from website. While receiving an email the font is changed in email. I need same font in email also.

please help me out from this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where is the email template ?

Comment: @gaurav5430 this html is for email template. and its in database. I am generating get html from db and send email but the font family is not working in that.

Comment: First of all, you can use the font from anywhere either from your local system or from the other website. But I would suggest you to download the font in your local system and then use it (to avoid network consumption) and also font-support in email templates depends on the email clients as well, so take care of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first convert ttf font to get all needed files [here](http://www.font2web.com/)

Here is your css code

```
@font-face {
  font-family:'XTX-FNT-XEROSANS-REGULAR';
  src:url('../font/XTX-FNT-XEROSANS-REGULAR.eot');
  src:url('../font/XTX-FNT-XEROSANS-REGULAR.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../font/XTX-FNT-XEROSANS-REGULAR.woff') format('woff'),
    url('../font/XTX-FNT-XEROSANS-REGULAR.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

Comment: While receiving an email the font is changed in email. I need same font in email also.

Comment: No you can link css and fonts in email not include them. I Placed sample code for you change this ../ to link for example: Yourwebsite.com/font/XTX-FNT-XEROSANS-REGULAR.eot  and so on

Comment: Please send me in file your full email code and font and I will send you email with this font. If any questions please ask

Comment: @lanfontein; Please give me your mail id.

Comment: lafontein@protonmail.ch

Answer (score 0):

Using @font-face or other modern techniques in html-emails is not well covered among email-clients, so I'd stay away from any modern things.

Most clients won't fetch external content just just as images are blocked, so are other external resources, such as .eot etc. Some clients might have support for data uris (https://css-tricks.com/data-uris/) but probably not well supported.

Instead, enjoy the 90:ies:

- Use tables for layout.
- Inline style="color:#123123" only.
- Fake any high-importance fonts with graphics. (Logos etc).